# ListView and dynamic row sizes

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-activity, resources

I'd like to use different row descriptors (from the XML layout resource) in one ListView. Can I and how?

Also, I'd like to be able to programmatically change the size of the rows, based on  the data in each row, in a ListView. Can I and how?

Thank you in advance--I LOVE stackoverflow.

M

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to use different row
>   descriptors (from the XML layout
>   resource) in one ListView. Can I and
>   how?

Step #1: Override your Adapter class and implement `newView()`/`bindView()` (or `getView()` if `ArrayAdapter`)

Step #2: Inflate the rows you want when you want them from the layouts you want

Step #3: Override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`, returning appropriate values, so Android knows to use different object pools for each distinct type of row

[This book excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) covers #1 and #2, though for only one type of row. I don't have any samples handy for multiple types of rows, sorry.

> Also, I'd like to be able to
>   programmatically change the size of
>   the rows, based on the data in each
>   row, in a ListView. Can I and how?

Put in bigger stuff in the row. Heights of rows are determined by their contents.